# Android Espresso: How do I inspect elements inside a web view?

Tags: android, kotlin, ui-automation, android-espresso

In the app is a [Checkout.com 3DS screen](https://www.checkout.com/docs/testing/test-card-numbers#Test_3D_Secure) and when I use Layout Inspector (Android Studio), I only see the web view but it has no subtrees. Do I need to use separate software to inspect elements in chrome web view?

I believe I have the correct code to interact with the elements but I'm just guessing the attributes at the moment and not having much luck. Using text/placeholder hasn't worked so far.

```
private val webView = withId(R.id.verifyByThreeDsWebView)

override fun isDisplayed() {
    support.waitForViewDisplayed(webView, 20000)
}

fun enterPassword(password: String = "Checkout1!") {
   onWebView(webView).forceJavascriptEnabled()
       .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH,"//*[@placeholder='Hint: Checkout1!']"))
       .perform(webKeys(password))
}

fun clickSubmit() {
    onWebView(webView)
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH,"\"//button[contains(text(),'Continue')]\""))
        .perform(webClick())
}
```

Comment: Can't you inspect the web and get the ID then find and interact the components through that ID?

Comment: I thought about that and it should work but problem is I can't find any test webpage for desktop, the project I'm working on is app only.

Comment: But if you copy the url to a desktop doesn't work?

Comment: No option to copy, it is embedded in the app.

Comment: I found the URL via layout inspector but it doesn't work in other browser.